# TreeSet like data structure which supports duplicate entries

Tags: java, treeset

I am working with Java and I am looking for a data structure that stores objects and sorts them based on one of the properties(Integer type) of object. For example, if objects  have different properties and one of these properties is called **number** of type Integer. I would like to sort all the objects based on the property **number**. I am also looking for the time complexities to be as follows:

- Insertion in log(n) time.
- Deletion in log(n) time.
- Get all the objects that have the **number** property in a certain range in log(n) time. The range has a min value and a max value. I would like to get all the objects that have the **number** property falling in this range and would like the time complexity to be log(n) in worst case scenario.

I believe TreeSet data structure in Java could be a good candidate to store these objects. I can use to custom comparator to sort the objects based on the **number** property. But the problem is this **number** property could be the same for multiple objects and I would like to store all of them. Initially I had a custom comparator like the following. But with this comparator, object with the same **number** property were getting overwritten.

```
class Helper implements Comparator<NumberWrapper> {
public int compare(NumberWrapper num1, NumberWrapper num2)
    {
        if(num1.number == num2.number){
            return 0;
        }
        else if (num1.number > num2.number)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

So, I removed the following code in the comparator so that objects with same **number** property cannot be overwritten.

```
 if(num1.number == num2.number){
    return 0;
 }
```

Now, the overall code looks like the following

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<NumberWrapper> set = new TreeSet<NumberWrapper>(new Helper());
        set.add(new NumberWrapper(2));
        set.add(new NumberWrapper(3));
        set.add(new NumberWrapper(2));
        set.add(new NumberWrapper(1));

        
        // Subset to hold all objects which have the "number" property greater than or equal 
        // to 2 and less than 3. (Basically all 2s)
        TreeSet<NumberWrapper> subSet = (TreeSet<NumberWrapper>) set.subSet(new 
        NumberWrapper(2),new NumberWrapper(3));
       
        // Output here will 2 , 2,
        for (NumberWrapper value : subSet){
            System.out.print(value.number + " ,");
        }
    }
}
class NumberWrapper {
    Integer number;
    NumberWrapper(Integer number){
        this.number = number;
    }
}
class Helper implements Comparator<NumberWrapper> {
    public int compare(NumberWrapper num1, NumberWrapper num2)
    {
         if (num1.number > num2.number)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

This code seems to be working as expected for me. All the objects with same **number** property are not getting overwritten. But I have a couple of questions

1. I am not sure if the compare method I wrote for comparator is not buggy. Will there be a chance that some of the objects with same **number** property will not be returned when I try to get all the objects that have the **number** property in a certain range?
2. Is there any other data structure I should be considering for my needs?

Comment: Apache Commons Collections has a few data structures you might look into.

Comment: Look at https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html

Comment: Maybe a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) where the keys are the property you are sorting and the values are a list of the instances?